# How to show tree list using phpseclib?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I am using library phpseclib. To show directory listing, I use function :

$sftp->rawlist();

But it don't show the tree list as image of its example (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html)

How can I do to show it as image below ? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

phpseclib's documentation is in git:

https://github.com/phpseclib/docs

Looking at it...  the documentation website uses http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/ to achieve the effect you're asking about. To convert a PHP array to HTML that'll work with that plugin...

```
function array2html($array)
{
    $result = '';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $result.= '<li><span class="name">' . $key . '</span>' . (is_array($value) ? array2html($value) : '<ul><li>' . $value . '</li></ul>') . '</li>';
    }
    return '<ul>' . $result . '</ul>';
}
```

So in PHP you'll want to do this (once the above function is defined):

```
echo str_replace('<ul>', '<ul class="printr">', array2html($arr), 1);
```

In HTML you'll then need to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.printr').treeview({     persist: "location",     collapsed: true,     unique: true   });
}
```

Keep in mind it does look like the phpseclib docs did make at least one change to the tree view library (modified some CSS and added a new image):

https://github.com/phpseclib/docs/commit/3406a94489c153ddf8f4a1a33f2ecbbcdd5ec61e

Hope that helps!